# Запятые, запятые

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Он сказал: «Давай мышка(,) выбирайся из пещеры!»
Нужна ли зпт в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна не только та, которая в скобках, но и перед словом "мышка". "Мышка" - обращение, а обращения в русском языке всегда выделяются запятыми с обеих сторон:

> Давай, мышка, выбирайся из пещеры!